# How to track emails which are not DKIM aligned

Tags: google-workspace, dkim, dmarc

I've set up DKIM on my domain and configured Postmark to send me a DMARC Daily Digest to monitor that everything is set up correctly. Each week, I have around half of my emails sent through Google marked as not DKIM aligned:

[image: Not DKIM aligned]

Any idea to how to track down the problem. I'm pretty confident, that I've correctly configured the email correctly in G Suite, which the `100%` indicators on the two other IPs also show.

Comment: Can you look at the raw DMARC data? Do you have access to the actual DMARC aggregate reports? If so, you might determine what is happening. For example, which servers/services are reporting the misalignment? If it's Google, you might very well be dealing with recipients also on Google, forwarding emails by Distribution Group, which will in turn generate misaligned emails. But without the actual reports (and possibly even with the reports) I'm just guessing here.
Can you access / provide such data / report?

Comment: I think you are right there. I don't have access to the raw data, but the type of emails I'm sending, are good candidates for distribution lists. Thanks. Maybe convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times, seeing DKIM (and / or SPF) misalignment in DMARC aggregate reports comes down to forwarding. In this particular case, you are likely seeing recipients hosted on Google having Distribution Groups forwarding to internal addresses. Google adds these DMARC authentication results to the DMARC aggregate reports it sends out, even though they are internally routed messages.

I've written an answer on this matter before [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119689/why-is-google-com-trying-to-send-emails-from-my-domain/119753#119753).